# Arduino NANO ESP32 pinout

Tags: arduino, esp32

I got an Arduino NANO ESP32 board, not sure if that's the official one or one of the clones but it seems like just a common NANO with a wireless chip on board.

The problem is Arduino IDE's ESP32 package doesn't have it in the list, so to upload my code I'm using one of their "ESP32S3" presets.

But the digital pinout doesn't match, for instance, the physical D6 pin is actually 9 in code. Found that accidentally checking one by one.

Any ideas where I can find the full pinout list for my board?

[image: Front]

[image: Back]

Comment: What is on the bottom of the board?  Photo would be great if possible, thank you.

Comment: Sure, added a backside photo

Comment: seems to be a new model, however no official release, only this https://bahrain.microless.com/product/arduino-nano-esp32-dedb0580-board-without-headers-240-mhz-clock-frequency-usb-c-connectivity-micropython-support-plug-and-play-debugging-512-kb-sram-abx00092/

Comment: Yes, searching the web for [arduino "DEDB0580"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=arduino+"DEDB0580"&t=opera&ia=web) returns only this one website, listed as new two days ago.  We might have to wait awhile before any data becomes available about this model.  Could try contacting that vendor and asking for a datasheet or any details they may have about it.

Comment: There is actually an official website (if you click on EU countries) at [Arduino CC](https://store.arduino.cc/pages/nano-esp32), however many links are broken. Arduino IDE's ESP32 package has `ublox-NORA W10 series (ESP32-S3)` listed as one of the board which is the ublox module shown on your NANO ESP32 board, maybe you can give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the documentation for the Arduino Nano ESP32, including pinout diagrams:

https://docs.arduino.cc/hardware/nano-esp32

Comment: Can you please explain the answer in the question and not only post a link?

Comment: Well, the OP was asking where to find the pinout. The documentation, including schematics and pinout diagrams, for any Arduino board is located on the official Arduino documentation website. Hence the link I provided. There's not much else to explain :)

Comment: At SE link only answers are discouraged, if the link goes down nobody will be able to see the answer. it is more relevant to take the information out of the link and post it in the answer. Such as copying the information and providing a source to where it came from.